# Cycle2 Carousel e Bootstrap bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, cycle2

Eu fiz um [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4lUC28p2H5P9BJoOLqvQ) para a galera poder visualizar o problema...

Setando a `col-xs-12` e `col-md-3` (usando a capacidade de `auto-width` do Bootstrap 3) ele destrói com o cycle2 fazendo com que o tamanho dos slides fique gigante. Alguém pode me ajudar?